# Ignore generated resources from Spotless

Tags: gradle

My Project is using `spotless` plugin. I need to ignore java files from the `generated-resources` directory. How to do the same.

This is how I am using the plugin.

```
 apply plugin: "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless"
  spotless {
    lineEndings = 'unix';
    java {
      eclipseFormatFile "eclipse-java-google-style.xml"
    }
  }
```

`sourceSets` has `generated-resources` directory included which I do not want to remove.

Answer (score 13):

You can specify a target for the spotless formatter which allows includes and excludes.

I use the following in the top-level build.gradle in a multi-project build where all Java code resides in subdirectories under the modules directory:

```
subprojects {
    ...
    spotless {
        java {
            target project.fileTree(project.rootDir) {
                include '**/*.java'
                exclude 'modules/*/generated/**/*.*'
            }
            googleJavaFormat()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```